# How to use paypal API credentials with srmklive laravel packege

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using the srmklive package for Laravel and have set up a sandbox account on the Paypal API dashboard and it works. I am trying to port it over to use the customer's live business account on Paypal but I can't map across the API credentials. The sandbox uses the following:

```
PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID=
PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET=
PAYPAL_MODE=
```

But all I see when I generate the details on Paypal business account is

```
API Username
API Password
Signature
```

How I go about using these on the srmklive package?

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://developer.paypal.com and create an app. Then click on the app and you will see client id and secret. It seems like you were going through your normal account page at paypal.com and not the developer portal.